# package.json version error on visual studio cordova ionic2 template

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ionic2, resharper, visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

I have used [**this article**](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic2/) to create an ionic2 app.It is working fine.But on the `package.json` file where it shows below error.Can you tell me how to solve that? I'm using Resharper latest version with VS 2015 community edition.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a version property to your package.json

`"version": "1.2.5"`
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: how do I know which version should I add to it ?

Comment: @Sampath the version is simply your project version just like `name` is your project name.. It could even be the version you have in `config.xml`

Comment: Yes, That is it.Thanks a lot @suraj